# How can I have an SQL CASE statement generate distinguishing output

Tags: postgresql, case

I try to create a binary column based on the value of another column. When `wijkcode` is 34406 `stadsdeel` should be assigned the value `Center`, in all other cases `Misc`.

```
update event_locations
set stadsdeel = temp.stadsdeel
from (select wijkcode,
             case wijkcode when 34406 then 'Center'
                  else 'Misc'
             end as stadsdeel
      from event_locations
      ) as temp;

select * from event_locations;
```

and part of its output:

```
34406;"Center"
34406;"Center"
34406;"Center"
34408;"Center"
34409;"Center"
34403;"Center"
34406;"Center"
31005;"Center"
```

While it should be:

```
34406;"Center"
34406;"Center"
34406;"Center"
34408;"Misc"
34409;"Misc"
34403;"Misc"
34406;"Center"
31005;"Misc"
```

All codes are 'Center'. Clearly I do something wrong. I have tried `case when wijkcode = 34406` but that results in the same output. Does some body know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that your subquery is not correlated to the main query. The result is a Carthesian product: every target row is updated with every subquery row.
You could add a `where temp.wijkcode = dst.wijkcode` to the query to pick only one row per row from the subquery.

(or use the compact form as shown in @forpas' answer)

---

```
update event_locations dst
set stadsdeel = temp.stadsdeel
from (select wijkcode,
             case wijkcode when 34406 then 'Center'
                  else 'Misc'
             end as stadsdeel
      from event_locations
      ) as temp
WHERE temp.wijkcode = dst.wijkcode -- <<-- connect temp to the main query
        ;
```

---

But you could also put the connection *inside* the subquery, it will now result in exactly one matching roe per row:

---

```
update event_locations dst
set stadsdeel = temp.stadsdeel
from (select 
             case wijkcode when 34406 then 'Center' else 'Misc' end as stadsdeel
      from event_locations src
        WHERE src.wijkcode = dst.wijkcode
      ) as temp;
```

---

Or, you can reduce the subquery to a *scalar* subquery, resulting in only one *value per row.:

---

```
update event_locations dst
set stadsdeel = (select
             case wijkcode when 34406 then 'Center' else 'Misc' end as stadsdeel
                from event_locations src
                WHERE src.wijkcode = dst.wijkcode
                ) 
        ;
```

---

or, you can combine the two queries into one: the table is basically updated from itself, anyway:

---

```
update event_locations
set stadsdeel = case wijkcode when 34406 then 'Center' else 'Misc' end
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I see where I went wrong. I went for the last solution as that is the most simple but I see where I went astray in my subselection. Dank!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the CASE expression as the value to be set:

```
update event_locations
set stadsdeel = case wijkcode 
  when 34406 then 'Center'
  else 'Misc'
end
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ak3qXkT7oXJULEwtDMGPg/0).
Results:

```
| wijkcode | stadsdeel |
| -------- | --------- |
| 34406    | Center    |
| 34406    | Center    |
| 34406    | Center    |
| 34408    | Misc      |
| 34409    | Misc      |
| 34403    | Misc      |
| 34406    | Center    |
| 31005    | Misc      |
```

Comment: Ah, how simple can SQL be. It worked great, thanks!

Comment: @Arnold is there any reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Comment: @Torpas, The answer of wildplasser contains the same answer as yours (see his last solution), but it also explains where I went wrong with my subselection which actually was my original question. As a bonus I got  a simpler solution from both of you for which I am very thankful (+1 for that). Sorry I changed my mind.

Comment: *The answer of wildplasser contains the same answer as yours* My answer was posted 2 hours before that one. It is very easy to find a solution when you there is already one there, right? As for the explanations for what you were doing wrong, do you really think that you need them when you see how simple is the solution?

Comment: I did think Arnold wanted an explanaton, so I gave him one, because I think understanding is more important than getting the right solution. [And I don't care about karma-points]

Comment: @wildplasser then why did you include my proposed solution in your answer?

Comment: I did not include it, I wrote it myself, It was the end result of a series of *reductions*.

Comment: Really? And why was it necessary to write it yourself? It was already there for so long. Check the timestamps.

Comment: Given my question and the code I presented in my question, wildplasser was the only one who gave me a thorough treatment of the topic and a good explanation where I went wrong. That helped me immensely because I am still not very well versed in sub-selection (to put it mildly). In the future I will be better able to handle sub-selections. I am glad that both of you wrote a much simpler version of what I actually needed. As I had worked for a whole morning I went of for a walk and noticed two solutions when I came back. I ultimately marked wildplassers as the desired answer to my question.

Comment: @Arnold *noticed two solutions when I came back...* No, there was only 1 solution in my answer and reproduced by the other post. Did you ask for a solution or not? Did you notice that wildplasser's solution was my solution that was already given? As I said everything about the explanations is very easy but not necessary in this case because the solution is so obvious.